# Can't access javascript object members while using mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm using mongoose library to retrieve data from MongoDB database and I'm having an unusual problem. I am working with these schemas:

```
var imgSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  data: Buffer,
  contentType: String
});


var carsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  _owner : { type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
  year: Number,
  brand: String,
  model: String,
  name: String,
  carImage: [imgSchema],
  kmTraveled: Number,
  fillups: [fillupsSchema],
  reminders: [remindersSchema]
})
```

And this is the code where the problem occurs:

```
app.get('/api/cars/:carId/image', function(req, res) {
console.log('Returning image...');
Car.findById(req.params.carId)
    .populate('carImage')
    .exec(function(err,car) {
      if(!err) {
        console.log('carImage: ' + car.carImage);
          console.log('contentType: ' + car.carImage.contentType);
          console.log('Data: ' + car.carImage.data);
       } 
...
```

The output is the following:

```
carImage: { _id: 555a1ae275c52a072dffaa1a,
data: 
{ _bsontype: 'Binary',
 sub_type: 0,
 position: 69702,
 buffer: <Buffer ff d8 ff e0 00 10 4a 46 49 46 00 01 02 00 00 01 00 01 00 00 ff ed 00 9c 50 68 6f 74 6f 73 68 6f 70 20 33 2e 30 00 38 42 49 4d 04 04 00 00 00 00 00 80 1c ...> },
contentType: 'image/jpg' }
contentType: undefined
Data: undefined
```

As you can see, *contentType* and *data* members are there inside the object, but when I try to access them it's like they are not there. What could be the problem here?
I should maybe add that images are actually stored in a separate collection, just like users, but I didn't include the ref in the cars schema. Could this be the issue here?

Edit: yes, this was the issue, it works now. Question dismissed.

Comment: Is it possible that it is a JSON string at this point and you need to do a JSON.parse?

Comment: I tried with JSON.parse but it doesn't work.

Comment: try `car = car.toObject()` then access contentType & data.

Comment: Yes, they are defined.

Comment: dumitru, I tried with toObject() method but the result is the same :(

Comment: @LazyDal Can you edit your question to include the schema definitions for `Car` and `CarImage`?

Comment: o.k., I will add them.